# Skipping/step filtering framework classes when debugging servlet

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

Hi I'm trying to debug a very simple and short *Servlet* & *JSP* codes that demonstrates a simple login. Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)

            throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        String user = req.getParameter("userName");
==>     String pass = req.getParameter("userPassword");
```

The *arrow position* is the location of breakpoint. After hitting the login button on the JSP part, I am brought to this breakpoint line. But after hitting ***step into*** part on the toolbar, It tells me there isn't such ***RequestFacade.class*** (not attached) or some kind. Here's the screenshot :
[image]

What I want is to tell eclipse to not *step into* to any classes that are not coded by me. I mean *RequestFacade.class* is a part of Servlet specific classes, I don't want to *step into* it, only around my predefined code. How do I do it? And here's my step filtering set-up:
[image]

But it will still step into this `RequestFacade.class`. How do I do that?

Comment: It appears that not all of those are enabled.

Comment: @nitind. I've checked everything but still it steps into that particular servlet's classes.

Comment: What's the fully qualified name of RequestFacade? More to the point, would it match any of the enabled filters?